# How do I send block of the resource module externally

Tags: terraform

I want to send block of security rule mentioned below to security group as an input,Is it possible in terraform?

```
ingress {
from_port   = 5985
to_port     = 5986
protocol    = "tcp"
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

}

If we consider variables,we have a provision to read the variable value externally

```
instance_type = ${var.instance_type}
```

In variable.tf, we declare instance_type.

Likewise,is there any option to send whole of the below mentioned block to resource "aws_security_group" "allow_al"

```
ingress {
from_port   = 5985
to_port     = 5986
protocol    = "tcp"
cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to send the whole block, but you can define a variable whose type is an object with a similar set of attributes and then use that object to populate the block.

```
variable "ingress_rule" {
  type = object({
    from_port   = number
    to_port     = number
    protocol    = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  })
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  # ...

  ingress {
    from_port   = var.ingress_rule.from_port
    to_port     = var.ingress_rule.to_port
    protocol    = var.ingress_rule.protocol
    cidr_blocks = var.ingress_rule.cidr_blocks
  }
}
```

The above assumes you want exactly one `ingress` block and just want to let the caller customize its contents. If you instead want to let the caller specify zero or more `ingress` blocks then the answer is slightly more complicated, but follows the same principle:

```
variable "ingress_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    from_port   = number
    to_port     = number
    protocol    = string
    cidr_blocks = list(string)
  }))
}

resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  # ...

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_rules
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port     = ingress.value.to_port
      protocol    = ingress.value.protocol
      cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidr_blocks
    }
  }
}
```

The first notable difference here is that the variable is now defined as being a list of object instead of just one object. The second difference is that it's dynamically generating one `ingress` block for each element of that list using [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks).

It's always required to fully define your object type and define how it maps to the arguments within the resource block, because this then allows Terraform to validate separately your own module code (whether you spelled the argument names correctly, whether they have the right types) from the calling module's object or list of objects value, and thus report any errors at the correct source location.

Comment: Thanks Martin,

When I tried implementing the first logic it throwed an error.

Error:

Error reading config for aws_security_group[allow_al]: Invalid dot index found: 'var.ingress_rule.from_port'. Values in maps and lists can be referenced using square bracket indexing, like: 'var.mymap["key"]' or 'var.mylist[1]'. in:

${var.ingress_rule.from_port}

Comment: Could someone please help me out in solving this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ahh, that part of my example may be correct. Maybe try `var.ingress_rule["from_port"]` (and similar for the others) instead, since that is what the error message you saw is suggesting that you do.

Comment: Oh! I think actually, reading that error message again, that you are using Terraform 0.11. My answer was assuming Terraform 0.12.0 or later. The syntax in older versions is different; what I described in my previous comment might make it work in Terraform 0.11, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot Martin,

Your answer solves the problem